# Jetpack compose and fragments

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

If there is some lifecycle related event like `unSubscribe` or `dispose`, how is it possible to use compose without fragments' lifecycle?

Comment: Do you have a specific example of something you'd do in a Fragment that you are not sure how to do in Compose? Sharing some specific code would help in making this very broad question which has many possible answers into something much more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to observe lifecycle events on the fragment or activity, you can use [LocalLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalLifecycleOwner()).

If you want to subscribe to some observable and ensure it gets disposed when the composable leaves the comosition, you can use [Disposable Effect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect).